# Import CuCim in Julia using PyCall

Tags: julia, pycall.jl

I am trying to load `cucim.CuImage` using PyCall.jl, but I CuImage is not exported from

```
cucim = pyimport("cucim")
cucim.CuImage("image.tif")

#ERROR: KeyError: key :CuImage not found
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sould it be cucim.clara.CuImage  ?  https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cucim/nightly/api/

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel No unfortuntely, Also, when loaded in python, it is only cucim.CuImage().